# Material design ember input binding not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, material-design

It is similar to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492069/material-design-lite-inputs-in-ember-js-app-loses-it-design-after-route-transiti) but totally reverse,

For me the material design is properly working, but the Ember valuebinding gets lost :(

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    {{input classNames="mdl-textfield__input" id="sample3" value=zoom}}
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Zoom</label>
  </div>

{{zoom}}

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    setInputObj: Ember.observer('zoom', function () {
       console.log('obeservercalled');
    });
});
```

No the **zoom** is not binding :(

Can anyone help me with this?

Note: This works fine

```
{{input value=zoom}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`classNames` requires an array, see the documentation [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/components/customizing-a-components-element/#toc_customizing-class-names).